# gcc can´t find includes

Tags: linux, gcc

I have configured and build gcc from source without encountering any problems except when I try to include a simple header file:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){
std::cout<<42;
}
```

I get an error saying it can´t find iostream.

```
$ g++-4.7 -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++-4.7
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7.1/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7' --enable-languages=c,c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.7 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.6 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-plugin --enable-objc-gc --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.7.1 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7)
```

I have also checked the include dir (¨/usr/include/c++/4.6¨) and iostream and the rest are present.

Is it looking for them somewhere else or what?

Os is Linux Mint 64bit

Comment: you can check your include file search by g++: g++ -v -c myccfile.cc

Comment: It seems that you might have two different gcc versions installed? Your g++ -v command reports version 4.7.1. However your include directory shows version 4.6. Is that maybe the problem? On my computer these two pieces of information match.

Comment: @StephaneRouberol managed to fix the includes problem using that but now I get: $ g++-4.7 test.c
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory

Comment: managed to fix that too by creating a symbolic link :) everything works now